# Control reaches end of non-void function in xcode

Tags: xcode

i have a problem with XCODE . my code is right but the xocde it show me. : Control reaches end of non-void function

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int rectangle(int h,int w,int &emvadon,int &peripetros){
  emvadon=h*w;
  peripetros=(h+w)*2;
}
int main(){
  int mikos,platos,emv,per; //kiria sinartisi(main)
  cin>>mikos>>platos;
  rectangle(mikos,platos,emv,per); //klisi sinartisis
  cout<<"Emvadon="<<emv<<endl;
  cout<<"Perimetros="<<per<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is your return value for `rectangle`?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this code is misformatted (it is invalid to put `using` on the same line as `#include`) and you mean this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int rectangle(int h,int w,int &emvadon,int &peripetros){
    emvadon=h*w;
    peripetros=(h+w)*2;
}

int main(){
    int mikos,platos,emv,per; //kiria sinartisi(main)
    cin>>mikos>>platos;
    rectangle(mikos,platos,emv,per); //klisi sinartisis
    cout<<"Emvadon="<<emv<<endl;
    cout<<"Perimetros="<<per<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This error is correct. `rectangle()` indicates that it returns an `int`, but doesn't do so.

From your usage, I assume you meant for `rectangle` to return `void`:

```
void rectangle(int h,int w,int &emvadon,int &peripetros){
    emvadon=h*w;
    peripetros=(h+w)*2;
}
```